# ubuntu-core --- change snaps repository

Tags: repository, ubuntu-core

I would like to run Ubuntu-Core to a board not supported officially by the distribution. In this way, I would like to change the snaps repository from the Ubuntu Store to a Private Store in order to control what package will be updated by my device.

Is it possible to use ONLY my Private Store/Repository instead of the Official Ubuntu Store ?

Thanks a lot. Best Regards.